# Error peek() returns \xff

Tags: ifstream, peek

I have some specific text formatting requirements for an assignment, so I am using peek() to try and see the next character and decide what to do, but sometimes my peek() returns \xff.  What could this mean?
It even stays at that point too.  After doing a couple of get() It can't seem to move past that point